# Publishing an application in Visual Studio 2010/2012

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I have a project built in Visual Studio 2010, with a copy of it built using Visual Studio 2012. Each time I click to publish the application and then email a zipped copy of the result(in either 2010 or 2012) I run into a problem where the application does not install at all with an error that the admin should be contacted or it installs and then a new copy of the same app does not(later on on the same machine). How do I fix this problem please? I have tried many of the suggested clickonce fixes on many threads already but I am wondering if there is a sure way to deal with this once and for all.

Comment: anyone able to provide me with a straight forward way of using publishing tool in Visual Studio as so far, I have not had much success with what I have been doing.

Comment: Would you please mention the error you are getting?

Comment: Can you elaborate what kind of project you have....is it a Web Site, Console App, WPF etc.? And I am not able to understand what you mean by `Each time I click to publish the application and then email a zipped copy of the result....`. Are you trying to create some kind of executable??

Comment: It is a windows app. Even when I publish to a remote server, does not seem to work fine as users are unable to simply click and download as I expect it to happen.

Answer (score 3):

In order to help you we'll need more details on your setup:

1. WinForms/Web/Console/Service app
2. Are you publishing it on local machine or remote machine?
3. Details of error message
4. Details of commands being run (VS -> Tools -> Options -> Projects & Solutions -> Build And Run -> MS Build Verbosity -> Diagnostic)
5. Are you using build and deployment package or not.

Turning on msi logging helps too. 
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html

In order to install *new* msi package on a remote machine you will have to uninstall the previous one first, afaik vs will not do that for you.

Comment: Would like to package it so I can send users a copy by email.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the target machine does not have the .net version installed that the application is requiring. Have you checked that the .net version against which you compile your application (probably 4.0 or 4.5) is installed on the target machine?

Comment: Target does have .NET installed. Currently my tries work sometimes and not so at other times.

Answer (score 0):

This is an open bug in visual studio 2010 . Consider using the following plugin

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22c5f085-d1be-44a3-b5a4-4710a467b972

The issue in Microsoft connect issue tracking system

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/588047

Has been corrected for VS2012

Answer (score 0):

I may have run into something similar once before... Have You tried including all of the .dll files associated with your project in the install?

looking at this from studio 2010:

1. In the properties page of your project navigate to the publish tab
2. under "install mode and settings" click on the application files button
3. in the application files dialog under the publish status column, make sure all of the files listed are set to either Prerequisite(Auto), Include, or Include(Auto)

Once you have included all the files republish and try again. Hope this helps.